# How can I convert IIS url rewrite rules to Tuckey rewrite rules?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am having great difficulty in trying to modify these rewrite rules to a version of URL rewrite that can work with Tuckey.

They currently work with IIS / ColdFusion but I need these to work with a version of ColdFusion that is run within Commandbox which uses Tuckey rewrite.

```html
 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                          <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                          </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>

                     <rule name="Dont Follow" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="jrunscripts[.]*|javascripts[.]*|images[.]*|css[.]*|assets[.]*|CFIDE[.]*|cfide[.]*|CFFormGateway[.]*|stylesheets[.]*|Favicon.ico|lucee[.]*" />
                        <action type="None" />
                     </rule>

                     <rule name="ColdFusion on Wheels URL Rewriting" enabled="true">
                        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                              <add input="{SCRIPT_NAME}" negate="true" pattern="^/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cf_scripts|cfide|CFFileServlet|cfformgateway|lucee|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|wheels/public/assets|robots.txt|favicon.ico|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm)($|/.*$)" />
                          </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/rewrite.cfm/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>

            <defaultDocument enabled="true">
                <files>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="index.cfm" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>

            <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
                <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
                <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            </httpErrors>        
        </system.webServer>
       
       <system.web>
           <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" />
       </system.web>

    </configuration>
```